# Spoiler syntax should generate <div>, not <blockquote>

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown, spoilers, semantics

The [spoiler syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) (`>! …`) produces this HTML:

```html
<blockquote class="spoiler">
  <p>…</p>
</blockquote>
```

However, spoilers are not (necessarily) quotes. The [`blockquote` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) must only be used for "content that is quoted from another source".

As HTML5 provides no other appropriate element for this purpose, a [`div` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) should be used instead:

```html
<div class="spoiler">
  <p>…</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Solution: stop using spoilers.

Comment: Solution: stop using StackExchange.  (joke—but seriously, how can a member of the team actually suggest not using a feature that *they* provide as a solution to an accessibility problem???)

Comment: Solution: [replace `blockquote` with `details` and `summary`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371724/340816).