# Add a warning about the inaccessibility of spoilers to the editing help

Tags: discussion, accessibility, spoilers, editing-help, keyboard

As I pointed out in October 2017, [Spoilers are inaccessible to keyboard-only users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301971/340816). That question has two answers suggesting more accessible alternatives, including one that relies on native HTML elements (`detail` and `summary`) that fit the task much better than the `blockquote` element.

Since the accessibility of spoilers has not improved in the last five-and-half years, can we please add a warning to the [editing help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) that tells users this creates content that is inaccessible to people who can't use a mouse?

Comment: How weird. It works for me in Voiceover iOS (no mouse!), though it's a very confusing experience.

Comment: @Laurel How did you move to the spoiler (presumably not by tabbing to it) and how did VoiceOver announce it (since it's a blockquote)?

Comment: In "container mode" I swiped forward from the previous paragraph, it said "reveal spoiler", I double tapped to interact, and then I had to swipe **backwards** to hear the content of the spoiler (that's the most confusing part). Also "reveal spoiler" was still there on the page, just visually invisible (interacting w/it leads to the page linked inside the spoiler, weirdly). Note: Usually a link would be announced as the link text followed by "link" and blockquotes aren't announced at all for some reason (they're treated like a separate container, much like a new paragraph or bold text).